# Best place to implement Oauth2 authentication - Angular or Spring boot

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, csrf

Our team is currently split between doing Oauth2 Authentication (**using third party Identity provider**) at Angular end or at Server end (We might have an intermediate layer at server end  like a** proxy layer** which does authentication etc. and then forwards the calls to the actual rest apis with bearer token attached).

From what I have researched in web, It looks like it is better to have the access tokens generated and stored at server end rather than front end** mainly for security purposes.

**Approach 1**
I am more inclined to Server side Oauth2 Authentication as well , where we generate access tokens at proxy server end and map this to a given user id who tried to login successfully as part of some token storage mechanism.
(or)
Spring itself has a lot of inbuilt stuff where the user session is already mapped to the access tokens etc as part of some IN memory session store and handle access token expiry seamlessly.. We might start off using this initially.

**Question **:- Is there any security loopholes with this approach where the only thing we pass to the client/browser from the server is a cookie which has just user id info and this is used in subsequent calls back and forth. The proxy server then picks up the corresponding access token of that user and send the api calls with this access token attached to request.

**Approach 2:**

Have all the Oauth2 Authentication done at the angular/front end . With the introduction of PKCE we might use this on top of Auth Code Grant type.
Once the access token is sent from the Identity provider we plan to store it in a cookie at front end and attach it for subsequent calls to and from the back end server.
This is less complex to implement when compared to approach 1.
And has a stateless approach which we are not really keen on and is not a must have.

**Question** :- Would there be any security loopholes with this approach .
I know if we plan to store the access token  as part of a local storage at your browser /system end there is a possibility of CSS attacks . But if we don't store the access token anywhere and just send it as part of cookie to backend server , from what I have read we might end up having CSRF attacks .
I am still to gain more knowledge with regards to CSRF attacks , but wouldn't it be the case with approach 1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Spring Security team latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), you should be using "confidential" OAuth2 clients on the server, not "public" client in the browser.

An option I use is to configure `spring-cloud-gateway` with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and the `TokenRelay=` filter between the Angular app and Spring resource server. I wrote a tutorial for that [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff#implementing-the-backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-spring-cloud-gateway) (you can try it [here](https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/)).

Spring implementation for OAuth2 clients handles the OAuth2 flows (how to get tokens from an authorization server), tokens refreshing and tokens storage (in session by default).

The `TokenRelay` filter replaces a session cookie with an `Authorization` header containing the access token in session before forwarding a request from a front-end to a resource server.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs .. I will review this in detail and get back to you for any questions. One question though  (I am 99.9% sure that we will not need multiple spring-cloud-gateway server as our user base is less ) .. but in case we end up having 2  gateway servers how should we address session management in this case ??   What do you think is the best approach ??  Does my approach  of having a Map of user id and access token at server end work ??

Comment: [Spring Session](https://spring.io/projects/spring-session) is made to handle sessions across instances. For tokens storage, Spring Security client implementation does it for you (in session). For replacing session cookie with access token in header, this is precisely the role of `TokenRelay` filter.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder what it requires for an answer to be acceptable or even just useful.

Comment: I wanted to upvote your answer but it says I am a new user and don't have privilege to do so. Thanks for all your inputs . This was very helpful.  I am currently trying to see if I can find examples  to store access tokens with the help of any of the Spring Session apis(link that your provided)  EASILY , instead of the IN memory session that Spring already provided ..